# How to display combined information from one table to another?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first

I am planning a database for my application. I'm new at this so be patient please. This is a simplified version of it:

[image]

I will be using code first approach with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 5.

My question is how can I add another column `Total_Price` in table `Orders` where this column will show the total price of that order based on the items' price that are included in that same order? Is this possible in SQL Server, or must I write C# code to execute this?

Edit:

the `Products` table would have an additional column `Price` for each individual product.

Comment: That kind of thing should just be calculated or stored when the order is inserted. Also, don't use the text datatype. It has been deprecated for almost 15 years now. Use varchar, surely you don't need more than 8,000 characters for a name or product description.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can do it in either. Can you share what issues you came across when you tried to implement this?

Comment: I really have a preference for meaningful names to `CustomerId` not `ID` and then `CustomerId` in the `Order` table, see how that matches?  Agree with others use `VARCHAR(MAX)` not `TEXT` if you really need a huge value possibility.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There are ORM's that spit out 'ID' at the PK identity on tables when you do code-first development as a default and then tablename_id for all foreign keys.

Comment: @dfundako - yes, does not make it "better" IMHO - and this is a DB diagram, probably would be better to have a code sample for that code-first but here we are :)

Comment: @Shepherd Create a Prices table with a product id) with the Create datetime2 and an OrderDate on the OrderItem to show which is active when that OrderItem was created - note the PriceId would show that Price/Item relationship

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Orders` VIEW that calculates the `Total_Price` and have your application hit the view instead of the table.

Another option is to add `Total_Price` as a computed column to the table.   The computation would have to call a function to query the items' prices from the other table(s)

Comment: Just to be 'that guy' and add complexity to what appears to be a simple app: What happens if the price of an item goes up or down?

Comment: @dfundako well that would depend on whether the prices are kept as a history or not.   If not, then the order's `Total_Price` would fluctuate with the item price, which would probably be bad.   It is not shown in the ERD where the price is stored.   The best place would be in the `Order_Items` table, where the price of each item would be kept just for that order.   This allows the history of the price to remain fixed, and allows for special pricing for specific orders.

Comment: How can I implement the second option? 
Also @dfundako I'd probably use ON UPDATE, so when I change the products' prices they'd be changed elsewhere. Though I'd have to try that out first and it also depends upon the function Alleman suggested.

Comment: @Shepherd the computed column?   Google `SQL Server Computed Column using function` for examples.

Comment: @Shepherd Not worth a whole answer, but I would insert the order price 1 time and never touch it. When a customer calls a year after the order and you have to pull it up, you don't want to have a different total because your item prices went up due to inflation.

Comment: I forgot to mention the price would be stored in Product table. So if add a 'Total_Price' computed column with this in mind how to proceed ahead? Is it better to add a new table 'Products' whenever the prices change? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @Shepherd see the second half of my first comment above.  I recommend storing the price of each item at the time of the order in the `Order_Items` table.   That way if the "current price" of a product changes in `Products`, the price at the time of the order is unchanged in the `Order_Items` table.   However, this is tangential to your posted question.